# SharePoint Workflow - Delete item without delete permission

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Please I have an issue I need to delete item by SharePoint Designer Workflow when get approval from supervisor, but I need to hide the delete button from ribbon for the Initiator user.

**Note:** I unchecked delete permission from Initiator group to hide delete button from ribbon, so he will not have delete permission.

so How can delete item and hide the delete button for the Initiator users??

Please I need your advice as soon as possible.

Thanks in Advance.
Omarn

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SharePoint 2010 then you can put the `Delete Item` action inside an `Impersonation Step`, then it's the person publishing the workflow that needs the delete permission